# Vue Plugin error - returns not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2, web-frontend

I'm currently exploring Vue JS Plugin and Im trying to create my own plugin, but after I build console returns "GlobalDataMethods is not defined". What am I missing here?

```
GlobalDataMethods.install = function(Vue, options) {
    Vue.getAPIData = function(paramObj) {

    }

    Vue.getFormData = function(formId) {

    }
}

Vue.use(GlobalDataMethods);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GlobalDataMethods` needs to be *something*. You're adding an `install` property to `GlobalDataMethods`, but you never *define* `GlobalDataMethods`.

```
const GlobalDataMethods = {}
GlobalDataMethods.install = ...
Vue.use(GlobalDataMethods)
```

Consider the VueRouter plugin. The [router definition](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/index.js#L18) is a `class`. The `install` method is [added to that class](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/index.js#L230).

Comment: so plugin needs to be defined first, thanks @BertEvans